# Cannot access my nested function which is inside the class

Tags: python, database, function, oop

So Inside a class I have a function and inside that function I have a series of functions. But I cannot call the nested function when I create the object.`user.searchBooks.AuthorBooks()` (where user is an instance of the object) does not work. I don't know whether I am doing this wrong. Is there another way of accessing the function

```
class User():
def __init__(self):
    self.ID = None
    self.Firstname = None
    self.Surname = None
    self.username = None
    self.email = None

def searchBook(self):
    '''Searching Books with given query'''
    def AuthorBooks(self, aFirstname, aLastname, Type):
        """Query based on Author Searches - returns books with particular author """
        if Type == 'All':
            query = ("""
            SELECT * FROM tblBooks;
            SELECT * FROM tblAuthor;
            SELECT cb.Name, cb.Genre, cb.Year_Published, ca.Firstname, ca.Surname
            FROM tblBooks as cb
            INNER JOIN tblAuthor ca on cb.AuthorID = ca.AuthorID
            WHERE (UPPER(ca.Firstname)) = (UPPER(?)) or (UPPER(ca.Surname) = UPPER(?));""")
        elif Type == 'Loaned Books':
            query = ("""
            SELECT tblBooks.Name, tblAuthor.Firstname, tblAuthor.Surname, tblBooks.BookID, tblLoans.Expiry_Date
            FROM tblLoans
            INNER JOIN (tblBooks INNER JOIN tblAuthor ON tblBooks.AuthorID = tblAuthor.AuthorID) ON tblBooks.BookID = tblLoans.BookID
            WHERE ((UPPER(tblAuthor.Firstname) = UPPER(?)) or(UPPER(tblAuthor.Surname) = UPPER(?)) AND tblLoans.Date_of_Return IS NULL;
            """)
    
        cursor.execute(query, [(aFirstname), (aLastname)])

        return cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the function `AuthorBooks()` is defined inside of `searchBook()`, this makes it inaccessible from outside of the `searchBook()` function. (All variables and functions defined inside of a function are generally only accessible within that function in which they were defined)

To make your code work, you could define `AuthorBooks()` as a separate function and access it directly using `user.AuthorBooks()`.